# Chat program in C++ returning infinite messages

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, chat

Here is a chat application code below which I'm having troubles with.

The chat system works by having a master server, where all clients connect to. So, here is the code for the master server.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sListen;
SOCKET sConnect;
SOCKET* Connections;

int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
int ConCounter = 0;

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ServerThread(int ID)
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char* Recv = new char[256];
    ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);

    char* Send = new char[sizeof(Buffer)];
    ZeroMemory(Send, sizeof(Buffer));

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        if(recv(Connections[ID], Recv, 256, NULL))
        {
            sbuffer.ID = ID;
            memcpy(sbuffer.Message, Recv, 256);
            memcpy(Send, &sbuffer, sizeof(Buffer));

            for(int a = 0; a != ConCounter; a++)
            {
                if(Connections[a] == Connections[ID])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    send(Connections[a], Send, sizeof(Buffer), NULL);
                }
            }
            ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int InitWinSock()
{
    int RetVal = 0;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);

    return RetVal;
}

int main()
{
    int RetVal = 0;
    RetVal = InitWinSock();
    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    Connections = (SOCKET*)calloc(64, sizeof(SOCKET));

    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(sListen, 64);

    for(;; Sleep(50))
    {
        if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
        {
            Connections[ConCounter] = sConnect;

            char* ID = new char[64];
            ZeroMemory(ID, sizeof(ID));

            itoa(ConCounter, ID, 10);
            send(Connections[ConCounter], ID, sizeof(ID), NULL);

            ConCounter = ConCounter + 1;
            CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ServerThread, (LPVOID)(ConCounter - 1), NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the source for the client chat:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

// For this we need to send two information at one time:
// 1. The main message
// 2. The ID

// To send more than one information I will use a struct
struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ClientThread()
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        // The server will send a struct to the client
        // containing message and ID
        // But send only accepts a char as buffer parameter
        // so here we need to recv a char buffer and then
        // we copy the content of this buffer to our struct
        if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL))
        {
            memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
            cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message <<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    int RetVal = 0;

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
    getchar();
    RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        int ID;
        char* cID = new char[64];
        ZeroMemory(cID, 64);

        recv(sConnect, cID, 64, NULL);
        ID = atoi(cID);

        cout << "Connected" <<endl;
        cout << "You are Client No: " << ID <<endl;

        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        for(;; Sleep(10))
        {
            char* buffer = new char[256];
            ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

            cin >> buffer;
            getchar();

            send(sConnect, buffer, 256, NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, everything works fine except when you connect for example with two clients (run app twice) and close one of them the client that closed the application spam the chat with infinite messages which never stop! Any help fixing that?

I would like to ask someone if possible to help me comment the source code!

Updated code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ClientThread()
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    string buffer;
    //char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        if(recv(sConnect, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer), NULL)!=SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            strncpy(sbuffer.Message, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer.Message));
            cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message <<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    int RetVal = 0;

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
    getchar();
    RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        int ID;
        char* cID = new char[64];
        ZeroMemory(cID, 64);

        recv(sConnect, cID, 64, NULL);
        ID = atoi(cID);

        cout << "Connected" <<endl;
        cout << "You are Client No: " << ID <<endl;

        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        for(;; Sleep(10))
        {
            char* buffer = new char[256];
            ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

            getline(cin,buffer);
            //cin >> buffer;
            getchar();

            send(sConnect, buffer, 256, NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your server gets stuck in a loop is because you are not using the return value of `recv()` correctly.

There are other problems with your code as well (abusing `CreateThread()`, for starters).

Try this instead:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addrlen;

SOCKET sListen;
SOCKET sConnect;
SOCKET Connections[64];

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

bool doSend(SOCKET s, void *data, int datalen)
{
    char pdata = (char*) data;

    while (datalen > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(s, pdata, datalen, NULL);
        if (numSent < 1)
            return false;

        pdata += numSent;
        datalen -= numSent;
    }

    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI ServerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int ID = (int) lpParam;
    SOCKET sThisClient = Connections[ConID];

    char cID[64];
    ZeroMemory(cID, sizeof(cID));
    itoa(ID, cID, 10);

    if (doSend(sThisClient, cID, sizeof(cID)))
    {
        Buffer sbuffer;
        sbuffer.ID = ID;
        ZeroMemory(sbuffer.Message, sizeof(sbuffer.Message));

        for (;; Sleep(10))
        {
            int numRecv = recv(sThisClient, sbuffer.Message, sizeof(sbuffer.Message), NULL);
            if (numRecv < 1)
                break;

            for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
            {
                SOCKET sOtherClient = Connections[a];
                if ((sOtherClient != INVALID_SOCKET) && (sOtherClient != sClient))
                    doSend(sOtherClient, &sbuffer, sizeof(Buffer));
            }
        }

        ZeroMemory(sbuffer.Message, sizeof(sbuffer.Message));
    }

    closesocket(Connections[ID]);
    Connections[ID] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
       Connections[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    WSAData wsaData;
    int RetVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &wsaData);
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (sListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Socket create failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (sConnect == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Socket create failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "bind failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sListen, 64) != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "listen failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;; Sleep(50))
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(addr);

        sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
        if (sConnect != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            int ConID = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            {
                if (Connections[i] == INVALID_SOCKET);
                {
                    ConID = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (ConID == -1)
            {
                closesocket(sConnect);
                continue;
            }

            Connections[ConID] = sConnect;

            HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ServerThread, (LPVOID)ConID, NULL, NULL);
            if (!hThread)
            {
                closesocket(sConnect);
                Connections[ConID] = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            }

            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

bool doRecv(SOCKET s, void *data, int datalen)
{
    char pdata = (char*) data;

    while (datalen > 0)
    {
        int numRecv = recv(s, pdata, datalen, NULL);
        if (numRecv < 1)
            return false;

        pdata += numRecv;
        datalen -= numRecv;
    }

    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI ClientThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        if (!doRecv(sConnect, &sbuffer, sizeof(sbuffer)))
            break;

        cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    WSAData wsaData;
    int RetVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &wsaData);
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (sConnect == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Socket create failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    do
    {
        cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" << endl;
        getchar();

        RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (RetVal == 0)
            break;

        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    while (true);

    char cID[64];
    ZeroMemory(cID, 64);

    if (!doRecv(sConnect, cID, 64))
        exit(1);

    int ID = atoi(cID);

    cout << "Connected" << endl;
    cout << "You are Client ID: " << ID << endl;

    if (!CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        exit(1);

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        string buffer;
        getline(cin, buffer);

        doSend(sConnect, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Given your recent update, you still have problems with your client code.  Did you even try the code I gave you above?  Below is a fix for your recent code, though I still suggest you review the code above, which addresses a lot of other issues with your original code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

struct Buffer
{
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ClientThread()
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)];

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        int numRead = recv(sConnect, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
        if (numRead < 1) break;

        memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, numRead);
        cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    int RetVal = 0;

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    do
    {
        cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
        getchar();

        RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (RetVal == 0) break;

        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    while (true);

    char cID[64];
    ZeroMemory(cID, 64);

    recv(sConnect, cID, 64, NULL);
    int ID = atoi(cID);

    cout << "Connected" << endl;
    cout << "You are Client No: " << ID << endl;

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        string buffer;
        getline(cin, buffer);
        if (send(sConnect, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), NULL) < 1)
            exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Regarding sending a message as sentence, I have to use string. However, then the strncpy(&sbuffer.Message, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer.Message)); will throw an error? Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Declare `buffer` as a single `string` instead of a `string[]` array, and get rid of the `&` in the first parameter of `strncpy()`: `string buffer; getline(cin, buffer); strncpy(sbuffer.Message, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer.Message));`

Comment: I still have a problem. I did everything as you said and the getline(cin, buffer) returns an error, as well the "buffer" in if statement if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL)!=SOCKET_ERROR). The error in the if statement says: "no suitable conversation function from "std::string" to "char *" exists.". I tried to use buffer.c_str(), didn't work as well, returns an error "argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"". And the getline() still returns the same error "no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list.

Comment: I never said to use `string` with `recv()`, so that is your bug for making that change. You can pass a `string` to `send()`, but you have to use its `c_str()` and `length()` methods for that.

Comment: Please check my code in first post (updated) and let me know where is my mistake. I need to finish this soon...

Comment: You are not paying attention to what has been told to you, and your code shows it.  Did you even try the code I gave you in my answer?

Comment: Hello... considering my English isn't quite good, I didn't fully understand what you meant, but your example definitely helped. I'm going to revise your version as well and fix my other mistakes. One last question - if I want to output a message when someone leave the chat, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

When a client disconnects gracefully, `recv()` will return 0.  When a client disconnects abnormally, or any other error occurs for that matter, `recv()` will return `SOCKET_ERROR` and you can then use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why it errored.  You need to handle both conditions and make the server "forget about the client" when `recv()` returns <= 0 (except in the specific case of `SOCKET_ERROR`/`WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, which is not a fatal error).  Currently you are treating a socket error as if you had instead really received data from the client.

You *are* testing the return value of `recv()` against zero, but that is not what `recv()` returns on an error (`SOCKET_ERROR` is actually an alias for -1, and `if (-1)` evaluates as true, not false).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to C++ sockets, I'm mainly starting off this example to learn them! Is this going to fix the error?
        if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL)!=SOCKET_ERROR)

Comment: Yes, that should do it. But consider how you want your server to behave now that the client is gone -- you probably shouldn't send any more data to them, for instance. When writing socket code, read the documentation carefully -- you'll more or less always need to check for errors. Another easily missed gotcha is that a single call to send() is not guaranteed to send all the data you pass to it -- you need to check the return value and possibly call send() again.

Comment: If the client disconnects *gracefully*, `recv()` returns 0, not `SOCKET_ERROR`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot! Does it matter if we use SOCKET_ERROR or -1? Another question is you said to handle the error (in this case what I did I guess) and "forget about the client". What do you mean by forgetting about the client? Isn't handling the recv() only enough? This chat is quite simple, yea, I understand. I would like to ask one more question while we're at it! It currently supports only ONE WORD phrases, as in, you can't use space! What do I use to make space support?

Comment: @JohnSmith: That is because you are reading the client's input one word at a time.  Use `getline()` instead of `cin >>`, for instance..

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've replaced, cin >> buffer; with getline(cin,buffer); and it throws an error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `std::getline()` expects a `std::string` as `output`, not a `char[]`.

Comment: You're right. That was a dummy question. However, editing the char to string, wouldn't it cause problem(s) to memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer)); ?

Comment: `strncpy(&sbuffer.Message, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer.Message));`

Comment: I'm having troubles changing from char to string. What I'm doing is declaring string buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};, the if statement is if(recv(sConnect, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer), NULL)) and the strncpy as you said strncpy(&sbuffer.Message, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(sbuffer.Message)); and I also use getline(cin,buffer); which also throws an error. What am I missing?

Comment: The errors are the following:
1. getline(cin,buffer); - no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list.
2. buffer.c_str() - expression mujst have class type

Comment: You might want to ask these as separate questions, they seem unrelated to the original question and space in the comment field is pretty cramped. However, you seem to be misunderstanding std::string -- std::string x[5] is not one string of length 5, it's 5 different strings. You don't need to declare the length of a std::string -- it'll allocate memory as needed internally. The right way to call getline(cin,x) and x.c_str() is with x being just a single string object.